# Identify Capital Letter in grouped words and insert a comma and space

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am working on a task where I have to copy/paste the content from website into excel.

But the problem is when I copy/paste the content in excel, it appears like this :

- Los AngelesNew YorkSilicon Valley
- Consumer InternetMobileB2BEnterprise SoftwareE-CommerceMarketplacesSocial

`Let s call Los Angeles an item which is merged with another item New York` and I want to separate these items so that information is readable like this:

- Los Angeles, New York, Silicon Valley
- Consumer Internet, Mobile, B2B, Enterprise Software, E-Commerce, Marketplaces, Social

When I noticed I actually realized that on website (due to some technical reason) I was unable to copy the comma between items and therefore every other item was merged with a capital letter with previous item.

Now please help me know is there an intelligent way to solve this problem because there are hundred of entries. What I see is this is how this problem can be solved:

1. Identify a capital letter which is not after a space and has small letter previous to it.
2. Insert a comma and space at that place and continue with the remaining string.

Please feel free to elaborate if this won't work and if there is an alternative solution. VBA code/ Excel Formula  - anything that can help me automate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With "B2B" it would be a bit tougher, but it works pretty well with the others:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Debug.Print insert_a_space("Los AngelesNew YorkSilicon Valley")
    Debug.Print insert_a_space("Consumer InternetMobileB2BEnterprise SoftwareE-CommerceMarketplacesSocial")

End Sub

Public Function insert_a_space(my_str As String)

    Dim my_char         As String
    Dim l_counter       As Long
    Dim str_result      As String

    For l_counter = 1 To Len(my_str)
        my_char = Mid(my_str, l_counter, 1)

        If Asc(my_char) >= 65 And Asc(my_char) <= 90 Then
            If l_counter > 1 Then
                If Asc(Mid(my_str, (l_counter - 1), 1)) <> 32 And _
                Asc(Mid(my_str, (l_counter - 1), 1)) <> 45 Then
                    str_result = str_result & ", "
                End If
            End If
        End If
        str_result = str_result & my_char
    Next l_counter
    insert_a_space = str_result

End Function
```

The logic is that you run `TestMe`. Or use as an Excel function `insert_a_space` and then give the string. The function looks for big letters (between 65 and 90 asc) and if there is no space or `-` before the big letter (asc 32) and (asc 45), it writes a comma with a space to the answer.

**Edit:
Workaround SaaS and B2B**
The idea is to introduce an escape symbol. Thus, whenever we see "\" we ignore it. This escape symbol is introduced through `str_replace_me` and should be explicitly written for which options it is.

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim str_1   As String
    Dim str_2   As String

    str_1 = "Los AngelesNew YorkSilicon Valley"
    str_2 = "Consumer InternetMobileB2BEnterprise SoftwareE-CommerceMarketplacesSocialSaaS"

    Debug.Print insert_a_space(str_replace_me(str_1))
    Debug.Print insert_a_space(str_replace_me(str_2))

End Sub

Public Function str_replace_me(my_str As String) As String

    str_replace_me = Replace(my_str, "SaaS", "Saa\S")
    str_replace_me = Replace(str_replace_me, "B2B", "B2\B")

End Function

Public Function insert_a_space(my_str As String)

    Dim my_char         As String
    Dim l_counter       As Long
    Dim str_result      As String

    For l_counter = 1 To Len(my_str)
        my_char = Mid(my_str, l_counter, 1)

        If Asc(my_char) >= 65 And Asc(my_char) <= 90 Then
            If l_counter > 1 Then
                If Asc(Mid(my_str, (l_counter - 1), 1)) <> 32 And _
                    Asc(Mid(my_str, (l_counter - 1), 1)) <> 45 And _
                    Asc(Mid(my_str, (l_counter - 1), 1)) <> 92 Then

                    str_result = str_result & ", "

                End If
            End If
        End If
        str_result = str_result & my_char
    Next l_counter


    str_result = Replace(str_result, "\", "")
    insert_a_space = str_result

End Function
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. But there a few glitches like TV, B2B and SaaS. Is there a possibility that we can exclude certain words from algo so that it doesn't effect them. Apart from this, it is giving 99% output. Thanks

Comment: See the update. You have to introduce an escape symbol and it would work with SaaS and B2B. With TV as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot your support. Indeed a great help. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the content from the website and paste the same into a notepad. Then copy the content from the notepad and paste it into the Excel.

Comment: It will take a lot of time. Plus I need to insert some commas as well. Isn't there a way in excel to achieve this . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please paste this code in VBA module.

```
Function AddSpaces(pValue As String) As String
Dim xOut As String
xOut = VBA.Left(pValue, 1)
For i = 2 To VBA.Len(pValue)
xAsc = VBA.Asc(VBA.Mid(pValue, i, 1))
If xAsc >= 65 And xAsc <= 90 Then
  xOut = xOut & "," & " " & VBA.Mid(pValue, i, 1)
Else
  xOut = xOut & VBA.Mid(pValue, i, 1)
   End If
Next
AddSpaces = xOut
End Function
```

After that go to your spreadsheet and enter this formula `=addspaces(A1)`
Copy the formula to all the cells that you want to change.

Comment: Thanks for your VBA code. But it is inserting comma before every Capital letter. What I want is actually insert a comma when you find a capital Letter and there is no space previous to it; In this case it will have a small letter attached to it.
For example: **Information TechnologyOnline Dating ** should be changed to **Information Technology, Online Dating**. Please suggest