# VBA swap words in a string

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA I've made an userform. It contains multiple text boxes in which the user can write text. In one text box the user is supposed to type in his last name. I've made a variable called `lastname` and then did `lastname = LastnameBox.Value`.

My question is:
If someone for example types `de Vries`, how can I change this in `Vries, de`. Or if someone types `van de Voort van Zijp`, I need to change this in `Voort van Zijp, van de`.

How could I make this possible in VBA?

Comment: How would you know what words to swap around? Is there a list perhaps you have?    Or could we assume that the first capital letter in the string is where you want to cut?

Comment: Or is the `de` where you want to swap? If there is not consistency, this will be a daunting task most likely. It would help if you uploaded a photo of starting strings and end strings. Enough to determine and validate a pattern is ideal

Comment: de is indeed where i want to swap. The words starting with an uppercase are the last names, the words without are 'tussenvoegsels'.

Comment: And if `de` is not in the string, just leave it as is?

Comment: The first capital letter is indeed where i want to swap

Comment: if de is not in the string, you indeed just leave it as it is

Comment: [This should help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41057199/identify-capital-letter-in-grouped-words-and-insert-a-comma-and-space)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try something along these lines.  Not sure how you are requiring separation, I used "de" as this

```
    Function NamesTest(strNameIn As String)

Dim a() As String

a = Split(strNameIn, "de")

a(0) = a(0) & " de"

NamesTest = a(1) & "," & a(0)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that if someones last name is van der Straat i need to change this in Straat, van der. Actually, the first capital letter is where i have to swap. But if there only is Straat, I dont have to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two options. The first will pick up the last word and do the swap. It pays no attention to letter case.

```
Sub LastFirst()

    Debug.Print RevLast("de Vries")
    Debug.Print RevLast("van der Straat")
    Debug.Print RevLast("van de drake")

End Sub
Function RevLast(Name)

    LastName = Trim(Right(Replace(Name, " ", String(99, " ")), 99))
    LenLastName = Len(LastName)
    FirstPart = Left(Name, Len(Name) - (LenLastName + 1))
    RevLast = LastName + ", " + FirstPart

End Function
```

The second only swaps of there is an uppercase letter.

```
Sub UppercaseFirst()

    Name = "de Vries"
    Name = "van der Straat"
    Debug.Print RevUpper("de Vries")
    Debug.Print RevUpper("van der Straat")
    Debug.Print RevUpper("van de drake")

End Sub

Function RevUpper(Name)

    FirstUpper = -1
    On Error Resume Next
    xStr = Trim(Rg.Value)
    For j = Len(Name) To 1 Step -1
        If (Asc(Mid(Name, j, 1)) < 91) And (Asc(Mid(Name, j, 1)) > 64) Then
            FirstUpper = Len(Name) - j + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If FirstUpper > 0 Then
        LastName = Right(Name, FirstUpper)
        FirstPart = Left(Name, Len(Name) - (FirstUpper + 1))
        NewName = LastName + ", " + FirstPart
        RevUpper = NewName
    Else
        RevUpper = "Invalid"
    End If

End Function

Function RevNm(Name)

    FirstUpper = -1
    On Error Resume Next
    xStr = Trim(Rg.Value)
    For j = Len(Name) To 1 Step -1
        If (Asc(Mid(Name, j, 1)) < 91) And (Asc(Mid(Name, j, 1)) > 64) Then
            FirstUpper = Len(Name) - j + 1
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If FirstUpper > 0 Then
        LastName = Right(Name, FirstUpper)
        FirstPart = Left(Name, Len(Name) - (FirstUpper + 1))
        NewName = LastName + ", " + FirstPart
        RevNm = NewName
    Else
        RevNm = "Invalid"
    End If


End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more general-purpose solution for the problem stated in the title (won't handle the specifics of inverting first name / last name, which is a different problem):

```
Public Function ReverseWords(ByVal value As String) As String

    Dim words As Variant
    words = VBA.Strings.Split(value, " ")

    Dim result As String, i As Long
    For i = LBound(words) To UBound(words)
        result = words(i) & " " & result
    Next

    ReverseWords = result

End Function
```

Usage:

> ```
> Debug.Print ReverseWords("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog")
> ```
>
> Outputs:
>
> ```
> dog lazy the over jumps fox brown quick the
> ```

---

To the OP though, this isn't about inverting the words in a string at all. The solution is to *parse* the given string.

> *The first capital letter is indeed where I want to swap*

So you need to find the index of the first capital letter in the input string, then extract the first & last name, trim them, then concatenate them.

This works:

```
Public Function ReverseFullName(ByVal value As String) As String

    Dim firstCapitalIndex As Long, i As Long
    For i = 1 To Len(value)
        If IsCapitalLetter(Mid$(value, i, 1)) Then
            firstCapitalIndex = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If i = 1 Then
        'already shaped as needed
        ReverseFullName = value
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim firstName As String
    firstName = Trim$(Left$(value, firstCapitalIndex - 1))

    Dim lastName As String
    lastName = Trim$(Mid$(value, firstCapitalIndex))

    ReverseFullName = lastName & ", " & firstName

End Function

Private Function IsCapitalLetter(ByVal value As String) As Boolean
    Dim asciiCode As Integer
    asciiCode = Asc(value)
    IsCapitalLetter = asciiCode >= Asc("A") And asciiCode <= Asc("Z")
End Function
```

Usage:

> ```
> Debug.Print ReverseFullName("van de Voort van Zijp")
> Debug.Print ReverseFullName("de Vries")
> Debug.Print ReverseFullName("Voort van Zijp, van de")
> ```
>
> Outputs:
>
> ```
> Voort van Zijp, van de
> Vries, de
> Voort van Zijp, van de
> ```